# How to apply changes to subset dataframe to source dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to determine and flag duplicate 'Sample' values in a dataframe using groupby with lambda:

```
rdtRows["DuplicateSample"] = False
rdtRowsSampleGrouped = rdtRows.groupby( ['Sample']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
rdtRowsSampleGrouped["DuplicateSample"] = True
# How to get flag changes made on rdtRowsSampleGrouped to apply to rdtRows??
```

How do I make changes / apply the "DuplicateSample" to the source rdtRows data?  I'm stumped
:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['DuplicateSample'] = df.groupby('Sample')['Sample'].transform('size') > 1
```

Or use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` if need faster solution:

```
df['DuplicateSample'] = df['Sample'].duplicated(keep=False)
```

Performance in some sample data (in real should be different, depends of number of rows, number of duplicated values):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
N = 100000

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample': np.random.randint(100000, size=N)})

In [51]: %timeit df['DuplicateSample'] = df.groupby('Sample')['Sample'].transform('size') > 1
17 ms ± 50 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [52]: %timeit df['DuplicateSample1'] = df['Sample'].duplicated(keep=False)
3.73 ms ± 40 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#Stef solution is unfortunately 2734times slowier like duplicated solution
In [53]: %timeit df['DuplicateSample2'] = df.groupby('Sample')['Sample'].transform(lambda x: len(x)>1)
10.2 s ± 517 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you V. much.  Transform is an area I don't know much of and will now investigate further.
Good to see alternative ways of achieving the outcome and very good to see timing info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample': [1,2,2,3,4,4]})
df['DuplicateSample'] = df.groupby('Sample')['Sample'].transform(lambda x: len(x)>1)
```

Result:

```
   Sample  DuplicateSample
0       1            False
1       2             True
2       2             True
3       3            False
4       4             True
5       4             True
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you V. much.  Transform is an area I don't know much of and will now investigate further.
Very helpful also to see an example of the output in an easy to comprehend little table.  That is extremely helpful I feel.